# Overriding Dexterity default view type

Tags: plone, dexterity

We have object which is let say xyz and its view is xyz_view which dexerity expect page template file. Is there any way to override default page type to controller page template rather?

So view should be xyz_view.cpt rather then xyz_view.pt ?

Regards,

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, no. Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 3):

There is no realistic scenario for using controller page templates for dexterity forms. There is also no scenario that I can think of where it would be easier than using z3c.form.

Comment: I understand that there is no scenario but our old object we have content type view as controller page template which we can control more sophisticated way rather then just page template. I wouldn't have used cpt view for newly created content type but this is one we need to migrate to dexterity with controller page template view.I will see if I can convert to page template and implement validation if there is no way to change this.

Comment: Let me explain our scenario, We have course object and view is having "book now" event. for each course we check candidate's eligibility against the course and accordingly we redirect to two different path. I don't know this can be done easily in page template.

Answer (score 1):

Include a form that submits to itself inside your view template and use the 'update()' method to process the request and redirect on some condition:

```
class View(grok.View):
    grok.context(IMyType)
    grok.requires('zope2.View')

    def update():
        if 'form.button.Submit' in self.request:
        input_value = self.request.get('input_value', None)
        if input_value is not None:
            self.request.response.redirect(self.context.absolute_url() + "@@process-this")
```

See [the five.grok manual instructions about simple views](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/five.grok/browser-components/views) for more information